# Highest Common Factor unique factorisation domain

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a UFD (unique factorization domain)

$a, b, c \in R$ nonzero. Take $d = hcf(a,b)$

Show that $a = dx$ and $b = dy$ for some $x,y \in R$ so that $hcf(x,y) = 1$

This seems like it should be simple but i cant seem to prove it as i thought the definition of $d=hcf(a,b)$ is that $a = dx$ and $b = dy$ for some $x,y \in R$ so its already true???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$R$ is a UFD with properties which follow from the name.

So you can factorise $a$ and $b$ uniquely into product of irreducibles, $p_i$, $q_i$ and units $u_a$ and $u_b$.

Let $d = hcf(a,b)$ ie let it be the product of all irreducibles that $a$ and $b$ have in common.

Denotes $x$ and $y$ the "leftovers". Do they have any irreducibles in common? What can you deduce about $hcf(x,y)$?

Note: $d$ could be a unit if $a$ and $b$ have no irreducibles in common.